# How can I traverse this list in this manner?

Tags: c#, linq, list, foreach

I have a list of objects that looks like this :

```
ID:2000
Title:"Title 1"
Description:"My name is Marco"

ID:2000
Title:"Title 2"
Description:"My name is Luca"

ID:3000
Title:"Title 3"
Description:"My name is Paul"

ID:4000
Title:"Title 4"
Description:"My name is Anthony"

ID:4000
Title:"Title 5"
Description:"My name is Carl"

ID:4000
Title:"Title 6"
Description:"My name is Jadett"
```

now, I'd like to browse (traverse) it with a for each. But I want to traverse it starting from the same ID. So, first a foreach for the single/unique ID (2000, 3000, 4000, so 3 steps). Than, for each "ID" step, each Title/Description: so 2 steps for the ID 2000, 1 for the ID 3000 and 3 for the ID 4000. List is ordered by ID.

How can I do it? Group by? Uhm...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, with a group by:

```
foreach (var group in items.GroupBy(i => i.ID))
{
    foreach (var item in group)
    {
    } 
}
```

Comment: But not what OP has asked for. "first a foreach for the single/unique ID ... Then for each "ID" ...". This order would be different. First the group, then all items, then next group etc.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, The "first foreach" should be 3 steps according to what he wrote. With your description it will be 6 steps.

Comment: No, OP wants to enumerate the groups first, hence 3 steps because there are three different ID's. Then he wants to enumerate  appropriate  items( so 1. ID=2000, two elements, 2. ID=3000, one element, 3.ID=4000, three elements). You can have a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13395770/284240) if you want.

Comment: @TimSchmelter : what is not clear in my question? Your code looks the same as Amiram one

Comment: @markzzz: The order is different as i've alraedy mentioned. Amiram's approach has a nested `foreach` whereas mine has consecutive `foreachs`. You have asked for: _"first 2000, 3000, 4000, so 3 steps and then 2 steps for the ID 2000, 1 for the ID 3000 and 3 for the ID 4000"_ Above code does following: _"first 2000 then 2 steps for the ID 2000, then 3000 and 1 for the ID 3000, then 4000 and 3 for the ID 4000"_.

Comment: No. 3 steps (main), where inside (for each step) there are 2-1 and 3 steps :)

Comment: But the order is different not the count. I'm very surprised that only Rawling has noticed it and even OP does not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `GroupBy`.

first the groups itself:

```
var idGroups = items.GroupBy(i => i.ID).ToList(); // omit ToList() if scalability is more important than performance since it creates a new list but doesn't enables to enumerate the result multiple times without querying again
foreach(var idGroup in idGroups)
{
    // ...
}
```

then all items of each group:

```
foreach (var idGroup in idGroups)
{
    foreach (var item in idGroup)
    {
        // ...
    } 
}
```

Comment: You're still missing a couple of `var`s (`foreach (idGroup in ...)`). (Not my DV btw; I think this is closest to what the OP wants.)

Comment: @Rawling: I should try to compile even the simplest things ;) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, first get a distinct list of IDs and then loop through them individually.

```
foreach(var id in objectList.Select(x => x.ID).Distinct())
{
    foreach(var item in objectList.Where(x => x.ID = id))
    {
        DoSomething(item);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Amiram Korach's answer is better - use `GroupBy`.  Mine performs the exact same function, it's just more verbose :)

Answer (score 0):

Why use groupby when you can use sort? I've done this with Tuple but substitute with your structure of choice. Group By is usefull if you want to do aggregate operations on the groups. You just want to sort and traverse.

```
var list = new List<Tuple<int, string, string>>();
list.Add(Tuple.Create(4000,"Title 5", "My name is Carl"));
list.Add(Tuple.Create(2000,"Title 1", "My name is Marco"));
list.Add(Tuple.Create(4000,"Title 6", "My name is Jadett"));
list.Add(Tuple.Create(3000,"Title 3", "My name is Paul"));
list.Add(Tuple.Create(4000,"Title 4", "My name is Anthony"));
list.Add(Tuple.Create(2000,"Title 2", "My name is Luca"));

var sorted = list.OrderBy(k => k.Item1).
                  ThenBy(k => k.Item2).
                  ThenBy(k => k.Item3);

foreach (var k in sorted)
{
    Console.WriteLine(k);
}
```

Result is

```
(2000, Title 1, My name is Marco)
(2000, Title 2, My name is Luca)
(3000, Title 3, My name is Paul)
(4000, Title 4, My name is Anthony)
(4000, Title 5, My name is Carl)
(4000, Title 6, My name is Jadett)
```